# Relation between circum radius, inradius and the angles.

Tags: triangles

Is there any relation between circumradius, inradius and the angles associated with a triangle?
Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$r=4R\sin (\frac {A}{2})\sin (\frac {B}{2})\sin (\frac {C}{2}) $ where $r,R $ are inradius and circumradius respectively

Comment: Proof of the above statement.

Comment: It can easily be found on the site