# Determine the ratio between the radii lengths of the circumcircle and inscribed circle

Tags: geometry

Find the ratio between the radii lengths of the circumcircle and the inscribed circle of a triangle
I have tried using the rule:
$$\frac{a}{\sin{A}}=\frac{b}{\sin{B}}=\frac{c}{\sin{C}}=2R$$
Where R is the radius length of the circumcircle but i did not get the asnwer

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Relation between circum radius, inradius and the angles.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2305666/relation-between-circum-radius-inradius-and-the-angles)

Comment: Hint: $\verb/Area/ = \frac12 ab \sin C = \frac12 r(a+b+c)$